# Custom listbox with move fwd/bwd buttons

Tags: wpf

I have a custom list box with left/right repeat buttons to scroll its content with content template as below:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ListBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <DockPanel>
        <RepeatButton x:Name="LineLeftButton" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="20" 
              Content="&lt;"      
              Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand}"      
              CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=scrollviewer}"/>
        <RepeatButton x:Name="LineRightButton" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="20" 
              Content="&gt;" 
              Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineRightCommand}"      
              CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=scrollviewer}"/>
        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray" Background="White">
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollviewer">
                <ItemsPresenter/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
    <ListBox Height="25" x:Name="listBox" Template="{StaticResource ListBoxTemplate}" 
         VerticalAlignment="Stretch"   
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel> 
    </ListBox>
```

it works fine. I would like the buttons to appear only when the content is scrollable, how would I do that in xaml ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code project article [WPF Custom ListBox with Scrollbar on the Background](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AutoScrollListBox.aspx) seems similar to your code example so this might be a good place to start.

You can also play some tricks within WPF itself to get the behaviour your are looking for, and to get a better understanding of how you might want your control to work.  The key to XAML I've included is that relying of the ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility in the trigger for the ScrollViewer only works if the scroll bar visibilty is set to Auto, but that means the scroll bar appears, which is not what you want.  My trick/hack is to provide a second ScrollViewer that I hide to trigger the RepeatButton visibility.

Look for the line: RowDefinition Height="0" to find the hidden ScrollViewer.
I am also using the MVVM pattern in this example, but I did not include the Binding details.

```
<Window x:Class="ListboxRepeatButtons.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="250" Width="400">
  <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}"  x:Key="repeatStyle">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=scrollViewerInactive,Path=ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility }" Value="Collapsed">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=scrollViewerInactive,Path=ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility }" Value="Hidden">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="listBoxItemTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="itemsPanelTemplate">
        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>
   <Grid>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="0"/>
       <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RepeatButton x:Name="LineLeftButton" 
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=repeatStyle}"
                    Content="&lt;"      
                    Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand}"      
                    CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=scrollViewerActive}"/>
    <RepeatButton x:Name="LineRightButton" 
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=repeatStyle}"
                    Content="&gt;" 
                    Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineRightCommand}"      
                    CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=scrollViewerActive}"/>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="scrollViewerInactive" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
        <ListBox 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"   
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Customers}"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
            ItemsPanel="{StaticResource itemsPanelTemplate}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource listBoxItemTemplate}"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  x:Name="scrollViewerActive" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" >
        <ListBox 
            Margin="0,0,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"   
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Customers}"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
            ItemsPanel="{StaticResource itemsPanelTemplate}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource listBoxItemTemplate}"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>            
</Window>
```

Comment: This gave me exactly what I was looking for!  One caveat - ensure that your ItemsSource property is not of UIElement.  Instead, use DataTemplate to template how content should be rendered.  I was binding originally to an ObservableCollection<Button> and never could get more than one of the StackPanels to render the buttons at any given time.  Switching to rendering via DataTemplate fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Apply trigger on RadioButton which checks ScrollViewer's property "ComputeHorizontalScrollBarVisibility" to toggle its visibility like this -

```
               <RepeatButton.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility"
                                    Value="Collapsed" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=scrollviewer,Path=ComputeHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility"
                                            Value="Visible" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </RepeatButton.Style>
```

You can add this style to your resource and can reuse it for other RepeatButtons.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove ScrollBars from ScrollViewer by retemplating it while HorizontalScrollBarVisibility is Auto.
Try this XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollviewer" 
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ScrollViewer.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
            <ScrollContentPresenter CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ScrollViewer.Template>

    <ItemsPresenter/>
</ScrollViewer>
```